# WPF MVVM and Data Acces Layer Organisation

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have developed my first WPF applicationa (tryingt) to use MVVM. I'm still learning and would appreciate the following questions answered:

1. Should I keep TestReportItem class in Repository class library or move it to it's own class library?
2. My ViewModel does not reference a Model. It refererences the class TestReportItem. I display the TestReportItem using XAML and a datatemplate to access a string field "Title". Is this acceptable/best practice?

[image]

TestReportItem

```
public class TestReportItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string SubTitle { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public bool HasTable { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public bool HasAdditionalInformation { get; set; }
}
```

TestReportItemRepository

```
public interface ITestReportItemRepository
{
    List<TestReportItem> GetAllTestReportItems();
    TestReportItem GetByName(string testName);
}
```

XMLTestReportItemRepository

```
public class XMLTestReportTestStandardRepository : ITestReportItemRepository
    {
        private string _filePath;

        public string FilePath
        {
            get { return _filePath; }
            set { _filePath = value; }
        }

        public XMLTestReportTestStandardRepository(string sourceFilePath)
        {
            FilePath = sourceFilePath;
        }
        public TestReportItem GetByName(string testName)
        { ... }

        public List<TestReportItem> GetAllTestReportItems()
        { ... }
```

Comment: It would be better to create a new library for all the viewmodel classes that you use so that you can access across the application along with your logical layers.

Comment: And if I had models - separate them out too?

Comment: Why don't you just rename TestReportItemRepository.Interface to TestReportItemRepository and keep the `TestReportItem` in this project? It seems to be a DTO for the repository.

Comment: @mm8 because it's an interface to the repository. The XML respository references the interface. This help with extensibility and abstraction if I want to implement another type of repo like an SQL database.

Comment: @Teebee15: If it's only "interface to the repository", why do you put the implementation in there as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVVM is a rule of thumb and not a dogma; meaning its really flexible. Originally MVVM was based off of the three tiered data organization system. View/Business layer/DB layer. And in a sense, it is just that.

> Should I keep TestReportItem class in Repository class library or move it to it's own class library?

Whether your classes reside with the main project or in an external class library is up to the design. If the design calls for reuse between different projects, then yes extract it. Otherwise being external does not add any value except in separation of work.

Remember that an external library is in a sense a different namespace to structure your code.

> My ViewModel does not reference a Model. It refererences the class TestReportItem.

As to `TestReportItem` it is a Model. Just because it has/may have methods and operations is moot. If one needs create partial class files where the *model* esque properties are contained in one partial and the operations et all are in another partial are fine and one achieves *separation*. But that is optional

> datatemplate to access a string field "Title". Is this acceptable/best practice?

Does `Title` get derived or generated by its being in the class. If it does, then yes, if not, place `Title` on the main VM and extract/build  it in the getter of `Title`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time answer my question and sharing your valuable knowledge :)